# Grabbing first occurrence of numbers from large string between two specific words?

Tags: jquery, regex, coffeescript

I have the following string (`field_data`):

```
<fieldset>
    <div class='control-group'>
        <h5>New Side Dish</h5>
        <input id="menu_dishes_attributes_1344897592128_side_dishes_attributes_70308623619760_name" name="menu[dishes_attributes][1344897592128][side_dishes_attributes][70308623619760][name]" placeholder="Name" size="30" type="text" />
        <input id="menu_dishes_attributes_1344897592128_side_dishes_attributes_70308623619760__destroy" name="menu[dishes_attributes][1344897592128][side_dishes_attributes][70308623619760][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <input id="menu_dishes_attributes_1344897592128_side_dishes_attributes_70308623619760_price" name="menu[dishes_attributes][1344897592128][side_dishes_attributes][70308623619760][price]" placeholder="Price" size="30" type="text" />
        <input id="menu_dishes_attributes_1344897592128_side_dishes_attributes_70308623619760_restaurant_id" name="menu[dishes_attributes][1344897592128][side_dishes_attributes][70308623619760][restaurant_id]" type="hidden" />
        <a href="#" class="remove_fields">X</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**And I want to grab the number between `[side_dishes_attributes]` and `[restaurant_id]` which is `70308623619760` and only the first occurrence or last occurrence but I basicly just need one instance of it.**

I know you can use regular expression and filter but whenever I use any of these, it either returns all the digits in the string or it displays all the sets of the number in an incorrect output.

The number I'm grabbing is not static so it changes every iteration of the code but the names `side_dishes_attributes` and `restaurant_id` are constant.

Here's what I've tried so far and here are the outputs:

```
field_data = $(this).data('fields')

start_pos = field_data.indexOf("side_dishes_attributes][")
end_pos = field_data.indexOf("][_destroy]", start_pos)
result_text = field_data.substring(start_pos, end_pos)
console.log("Result:", result_text)
```

Output:

```
Result: side_dishes_attributes][70208369492160][name]&quot; placeholder=&quot;Name&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; /&gt;    &lt;input id=&quot;menu_dishes_attributes_70208370296900_side_dishes_attributes_70208369492160__destroy&quot; name=&quot;menu[dishes_attributes][70208370296900][side_dishes_attributes][70208369492160
```

And I've tried:

```
result = field_data.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
console.log(result)
```

Output:

```
227020836200328070208362003280702083620032803070208...
```

I have also tried playing around with this:

http://rubular.com/r/r5iowGGmw4

But I don't know much about regular expressions to get this to work properly.

I'd appreciate any pointers. I'm doing all this in jQuery Coffeescript (but if you show me code in only jQuery, I can convert it over too).

### Possible Answer?

```
start_pos = field_data.indexOf("side_dishes_attributes][") + 24
end_pos = field_data.indexOf("][name]", start_pos)
result_text = field_data.substring(start_pos, end_pos)
console.log("Result", result_text)
```

I got the right output using this but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Can we assume there is no way to get that number before the string is created? Where is the number coming from? Can it be pulled from a database?

Comment: Just the last number in the hidden-input?

Comment: @jackwanders The number is generated from `new Date().getTime()` but its part of a complex nested form function that I created following [RailsCast #196 Nested Model Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). But in my example, its two levels deep so I can't simply use `time`.

Comment: @DavidThomas Just `70308623619760` between `[side_dishes_attributes][70308623619760][restaurant_id]` or the end can be `[price]` or you can even grab it from the `id=` values.

Comment: If you wrote the function that builds the form, can you create a hidden input that contains the number as its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML string is stored in a variable, say `str`, you can do:

```
var matches = str.match(/side_dishes_attributes_(\d+)_/);
var number = matches[1];
```

This will give you an array with two elements. The first is the full string that matches the regular expression "side_dishes_attributes_70308623619760", and the second is the string captured by the parentheses, "70308623619760". `matches[1]` will contain your number.

By leaving out the `g` modifier, the expression only matches once, so it will return the number contained in the `id` of the first input

Comment: Thank you. This produced the results I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @Luke and @jackwanders that other approaches are preferrable, *if* you really only have the data in a string, here is a regex I believe will do the trick:

```
data.match /\[side_dishes_attributes\]\[(.*)\]\[restaurant_id\]/
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Linus, I appreciate it. I was able to produce the results I wanted from other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.control-group input').each(function() {
    var match = $(this).attr('id').match(/side_dishes_attributes_(\d*)_restaurant_id/);
    if (match) {
        alert(match[1]); // -> 70308623619760
        return false;
    }
});​
```

It will loop over all the input elements and break if your match is found.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rSghe/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're building this id from the server. So why not add just that number in another html attribute like `rel`?